# Anyone please do have Netflow data using nfdump in csv file?

Tags: csv, ip, netflow

- I had collected data using tcpdump but i want data from nfdump as a csv file.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nfdump -r /tmp/nfcapd.201712052349 -o csv > /var/log/netflow/test.csv
```

Comment: I don’t know why this was voted down it works just fine.